# Do i need one field index if i create two field index in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table 'orders' with fields

- id
- user_id
- project_id
- etc..

where two type of selects

1. > select * form orders where user_id = val1

and

2. > select * form orders where user_id = val1 and project_id = val2

If I create multi colum index for second type of selects on user_id+project_id Do i need to create
one column index on user_id to spped up first type of selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one index for the table . . . `orders(user_id, project_id)`.  This can be used for both queries because the left most keys (`user_id`) have an equality condition in the first query.  However, the keys need to be in this order.

MySQL has pretty good [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on multi-column indexes.